# Angular2 how to re attach click event on cloned elements?

Tags: angular, typescript, dom

I have a table list created with `*ngFor`, each list item has a details div that is hidden, and a show details button.
At the end of list items, out of table div I have an empty div, when I click on show details of each table item I get its details div and add as inner html of my empty div, and animate that div.
My details div has a button that I have bind a click event to that, but when I cloned that, its click event is not firing.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items">
   <div id="item-div">
    .......
    .......
    <button (click)="showDetails($event, item._id)">Show Details</button>
   </div>

   <!--  Item details (hide)  -->
   <div id="item-details" class="item-details-info">
     .........
     .........
     .........
     <button (click)="saveItem(item._id)">Save Item</button>

   </div>

</li>

<!-- Custom popup like div, but its not a popup, its an animated div -->
<div id="custom-animated-div" class="custom-popup">
   <div class="popup-data"></div>
   <div class="popup-close" (click)="closePopup();">
      <i class="material-icons">&#xE5CD;</i>
   </div>
</div>
```

And my component code for cloning and animation is:

```
showDetails (event: any, itemId: string) {
   var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
  this.togglePopup(target, itemId);
}

togglePopup(element: any, itemId: string) {
   this.popup = document.querySelector('.custom-popup');
   if (this.popup.classList.contains('active')) {
   this.closePopup();
   setTimeout(this.togglePopup, 600);
}
else {
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelector('.custom-popup').classList.add('active');
    this.cloneInfo(element, itemId);
  }, 100);
  // this.popup.addClass('active');
 }
}


cloneInfo(element: any, jobId: string) {
  var parentElement = $(element).parents('.item-row').find('.item-details-info');
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelector('.custom-popup').children.item(0).innerHTML = parentElement.html();
    document.querySelector('.custom-popup').children.item(0).classList.add('fadeInUp');

  }, 100);
}
```

But when my animated div cloned its contained button event is not working,I have even tried to add event inside clone function with `addEventListner`.

Comment: You use Angular in wrong way. Don't clone elements. Don't use `document.querySelector`

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Know that with change it with elementRef.

Comment: Use CSS for animation - and bind/undind css class (with animation) to your elements

Comment: In your component typescript file you shoud create field "itemDetails" - and this fmethod `showDetails(item) { this.itemDetails = item ;}` . And in your *ngFor `<button (click)="showDetails(item)">Show Details</button>`. And in `<div id="item-details"...>` put content of itemDetails fields...

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment yet but you should use `ViewContainerRef` and `TemplateRef` instead of `innerHTML`, bindings instead of `classList.add` and everything will work.

Comment: How about my animation class, how can I do that ?

Comment: Angular has built-in animations. Or you can render each template and show/hide them using css, without innerHTML. Angular's change detection uses underlying virtual dom and can become broken after innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

You can use interpolation `{{}}` to show the detail

In typescript file you can create a new item of item and on click `showDetails($event, item)` you can do:

```
showDetails(item:Item){
this.newitem = item;
//now 
}
```

At html

```
<div *ngIf="newitem" id="custom-animated-div" class="custom-popup">
   <div class="popup-data"> 
       {{newitem._id}} 
        <br> 
        {{newitem.name}} </div>
        <div class="popup-close" (click)="closePopup();">
        <i class="material-icons">&#xE5CD;</i>
   </div>
</div>
```